# XSLT Count() between two values

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to get a count between range of 100 to 199 (both are inclusive) for an attribute, but I am unable to join two results. Please help me out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
<cd>
    <title code="120">Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title code="200">Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title code="100">Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>19.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

The XSLT for above XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<xsl:value-of select="count(//cd/title[@code &gt;= 100 and 199 &lt;= @code])"/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help me out to resolve this problem

Comment: You're checking if code > 100 and code > 199... change `199 &lt;= @code` to `@code &lt;= 199`.

Comment: @Kenney I tried both but I am unable to get the count

Comment: Just use `&gt;` for both tests: `count(//cd/title[@code >= 100 and 199 >= @code])` (`>` shouldn't need to be escaped as `&gt;`, so it's fine either way) http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGcn

Comment: If I run it as is, I get `1` which is ok (there's only 1 album with @code > 199). If i run it with my proposed change I get `2`, which is also correct. How are you running it? What output are you getting? What do you mean with "unable to get the count"?

Comment: @DanielHaly Its working fine for me now:) Thank you

Comment: @Kenney I got count 2 as per DanielHaly's suggestion :) Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. (`[@code &gt;= 100 and @code &lt;= 199 ]` works too btw ;-))

Comment: This is a little bit (5 characters) shorter: `count(//cd/title/@code[. > 99 and 200 > .])`  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `&gt;` for both tests:

```
count(//cd/title[@code >= 100 and 199 >= @code])
```

`>` shouldn't *have* to be escaped as `&gt;`. It's fine either way.

Working example: http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGcn

Comment: Daniel, this is a little bit (5 characters) shorter: `count(//cd/title/@code[. > 99 and 200 > .])`  :)